# Unable to use eval(parse(...)) in data.table [,:=] function

Tags: r, data.table

I am not sure if I made an error here (dangers of using `eval(parse(...))`perhaps), but here I tried to use `eval(parse(...))` while updating a `data.table` column, which creates an error. Below is my code.

```
require(data.table)
# Loading required package: data.table
# data.table 1.9.2  For help type: help("data.table")
DT<-data.table(x=seq(1,10,1),
               y=seq(2,20,2))
DT[,y:=y*eval(parse(text="1*2"))] #Doesn't work
# Error in y * expression(1 * 2) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
variable <- eval(parse(text="1*2"))
DT[,y:=y*variable] #Works
DT
#     x  y
# 1:  1  4
# 2:  2  8
# 3:  3 12
# 4:  4 16
# 5:  5 20
# 6:  6 24
# 7:  7 28
# 8:  8 32
# 9:  9 36
#10: 10 40
```

Comment: Thanks. Have filed [bug #5423](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5423&group_id=240&atid=975).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This behaviour, [bug #5423](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=5423&group_id=240), is now fixed in commit #1234 in the current development version of data.table v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=1234):

> o `DT[,y := y * eval(parse(text="1*2"))]` resulted in error unless `eval()` is wrapped with paranthesis. That is, `DT[,y := y * (eval(parse(text="1*2")))]`. Now fixed, closes #5423. Thanks to Wet Feet for reporting and to Simon O'Hanlon for identifying the issue [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375404/unable-to-use-evalparse-in-data-table-function/22375557#22375557).

---

Regardless of why you want to do this and the relative merits or not, this is about order of precedence. You need to wrap the whole `eval(parse(text="1*2"))` in a set of parentheses to ensure that it is evaluated *before* you try to multiply it by `y`...

```
DT[,y:=y*(eval(parse(text="1*2")))] 
#     x  y
# 1:  1  4
# 2:  2  8
# 3:  3 12
# 4:  4 16
# 5:  5 20
# 6:  6 24
# 7:  7 28
# 8:  8 32
# 9:  9 36
#10: 10 40
```

Without the parentheses `data.table::":="` is trying to multiply `y` by an `expression` object, which will result in a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, actually the reason for doing this is to allow the user to key in fractions in a script. Creating an additional variable just to do this (in a loop) seemed very wasteful!

Comment: R evaluates `10 * eval(parse(text="1*2"))` just fine without any extra parens - this is something specific to data table.

Comment: @hadley fine, but the solution is *still* correct (so I disagree with your downvote), and I still think the reason it is not working is still because `*` sees an expression object due to `eval` not having been evaluated. I will change `R` to `data.table::":="`